# Stack divs horizontally according to size of container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a CSS(3) trick to stack divs horizontally if they don't fit in their container? If the container is smaller than the sum of widths of the divs, they should overlap each other, the first aligned to the left, the last to the right, until there is just one div visible if the container is too small.

I thought of a table or ul, but I didn't got the desired result.

If this is not possible with CSS, I will go for a JS solution with jQuery. This will be easyer, but not as nice as CSS.

Comment: Is it a <ul> <li> with li{display: inline;} you want or not ? http://jsfiddle.net/fMWwH/

Comment: I don't think this can be done with css alone

Comment: In your jsfiddle, the items are breaking into two lines/rows instead of overlapping if the container is too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fit them inline, this is used: `display: inline`.

If they don't fit in, you can use `max-width` for the child elements. Or you can use `width: 90%` for the child, so it always fill and shrink to the 90% of the parent element.

Otherwise in CSS3, you can use media queries, to detect the current browser size and then change the properties.

You cannot check the width or height of elements in CSS, for that you will require JS or jQuery.

In jQuery just use this:

```
$('selector').css('width');
```

And use it! And then using `z-index` overlap them all so that they are overlapping each other if the width is less for them :) Or try to set some sort of `max-width` so that they are aligned respective to the current size.

But you can check the browser size using CSS3 Media Queries, so that you will know what is the size of the elements now and change their properties! CSS3 Media Query might be an alternative if you don't want to use jQuery but CSS. But its not that much efficient as you will get the widths of the devices and their screens not the elements.

#### Reference:

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/